# Need a code to append or edit ms access database using C#

Tags: c#

im a total noob on C#, most of my codes came from searches and youtube. i became stock on one problem tho, how to Append/Edit my data in my ms access database, my code is like, i click on the data on the gridview and the columns show up on the text boxes, what i want is i just edit some of those textboxes and press a button and the new data would be saved to my access database, is it possible?

Here is what my searches and youtube done so far:

```
private void Txt_edit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        String email = this.gbGridView1.SelectedItems[0].SubItems[2].Text;
        connection.Open();

        OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();

        cmd.Connection = connection;
        cmd.CommandText = "Update Globalbet SET Shopname='" + txt_shopname.Text +
                          "'Where Email='" + email + "'";

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        cmd.Dispose();
        connection.Close();

        MessageBox.Show("Update Successfully");


    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Error Update" + ex);
    }
}
```

but this also have an error, it says:

> "'DataGridView' does not contain a definition for 'SelectedItems' and no accessible extension method 'SelectedItems' accepting a first argument of type 'DataGridView' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"

Comment: `DataGridView` indeed does not have a property called `SelectedItems`.  You're always encouraged to check the documentation for what it does have: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview?view=netframework-4.8#properties  Did you mean to use `SelectedRows`?

Comment: the code you shown  above is written on aspx. cs page of same aspx file? can you share complete code?

Comment: Aside from knowing which row to add/update rows, your way of doing by appending string together will make you WIDE-OPEN to SQL-Injection.  Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61663497/datetime-format-changes-upon-oledbcommand-executenonquery/61670419#61670419 for parameterizing your queries as an example.  Also, you can search such as C# parameterize queries, etc for future.

Comment: Thats what i have been looking for SelectedRows, thanks David. although im sure SubItems and .Text will have an issue but ill try youtube and search again for that, thanks David.

Comment: @DRapp i think i dont have to worry about sql injections for now, this form is just for me..

Comment: Although that may be, if you start this way and eventually trickles into production in other areas, harder to resolve.  Just a strong suggestion of better way to be doing it correctly.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion DRapp..